# Best Practice to have option to disable App notification

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm developing an application which uses Notification a lot and I expect users "might" be annoyed with too many notifications.

Thus, I thought to add an option in the application settings to stop receiving notification, either by sync user choice with server, or the app will just unregisetr notification:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

However, i notice iPhone settings already have options to disable notification per each app.

Hence, I wonder if it's a good,and common practice to duplicate this option in App settings, or assume that the user are familiar with the notification disable option in iphone settings.

I notice for example "WhatsApp" application have option to disable notification in the application itself.

Comment: I don't see it as a bad practice to include an option to disable notifications from the app settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some advice based on my experience. Of course, it needs server-side settings:

1. Allow user to choose what notification he wants to receive. You might have different kind of notifications, some might interest the users, some others less.
2. iOS doesn't really has a good tutorial about enabling/disabling notifications (for new users buying an iDevice). So don't expect that he'll know fore sure how to disable them. Some users will even delete your app just to get rid of the notifications. And don't expect that a tutorial to disable them will have a great impact.
3. Have a "sleep" mode where the user doesn't receive any notification during a part of the day. However iOS6, user can do it himself with device setting, so I don't really recommend you to implement it :-) But before it was a "nice to have".

But be strong with your users. Notifications might be an important part of your app/business. So don't allow too much "customization".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's neither good practice nor common practice to duplicate standard notification settings in the app's own settings. For example, when you go to the notifications section of the Settings app, turn on notifications for your app, it would be reasonable for the user to assume they'll get notifications. They shouldn't have to remember to visit your app's specific settings, too.

If you absolutely need a user interface to refine what notifications a user gets, fine, offer that in your app's own settings. But otherwise, I'd advise against it. And even then, I'd ask whether your app really needs that level of control. Rich and finely-grained app-specific settings tends to make an app less graceful and less intuitive. Sometimes you really need that control (in which case, do it), but the most elegant apps tend to have the most minimalist interfaces.

Many of us are software engineers, but we can't let the "inner engineer" in us bias our UX too much. We have to put on our "digital creative" hats and think about how to make that sublime user experience. Often, less is more.

---

By the way, if you're worried about the user objecting to too many notifications, then you almost certainly have too many notifications. Look at what notifications you have and ask whether they're really worthy of interrupting the user who is doing something else.